# Combinatorics - weight function and coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

Disclaimer, this is an assignment question and please just leave some hints so I can learn and try to solve myself :)

Q: Let *S* be a set of objects, and let *w* be a weight function on elements of *S*. Let $ F_{s}(x) $ be the generating series of *S* with respect to *w*. Determine (with explanations) which objects in *S* does the following coefficient count.

$$ [x^{n}]\frac{F_{s}(x)}{1-x} $$

My course definition is that, $[x^{n}]F_{s}(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^{n}$

I have tried changing the $\frac{1}{1-x}$ into summation form, and basically get $[x^{n}]F_{s}(x)\sum_{n\geq0}x^{n}$

However I am not sure what the next step is. I am not sure how to **determine which objects in *S* does the coefficient count.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: We know that

$$F_s(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\;,$$

where $a_n$ is the number of objects in $S$ with weight $n$. We also know that

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;,$$

so that

$$\frac{F_s(x)}{1-x}=\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

This product is another power series; if we denote it by $\sum\limits_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n$, then

$$[x^n]\frac{F_s(x)}{1-x}=[x^n]\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n=c_n\;.$$

Thus, we need to know how to get $c_n$ from the product on the righthand side of $(1)$. This is an instance of a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series). At the link you’ll find a formula; it’s just like ordinary multiplication of polynomials.

Once you see how to express $c_n$ in terms of the coefficients $a_k$ for suitable values of $k$, it shouldn’t be too hard to see what $c_n$ counts; just remember that $a_k$ is the number of objects in $S$ with weight $k$.

Comment: Could you please just elaborate a little bit on what it means by "$a_{k}$ is the number of objects in _S_ with weight _k_?" It's my first time taking combinatorics and it's quite confusing with these terminology. Or pointing me to an easily understandable literature would be great too. My course notes are all constructed in a very succinct and Mathematical way that is hard for my brain to digest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @HarBear: It just means that in some way we’ve assigned to each object in $S$ an integer, called the *weight* of that object. As examples, if $S$ were a set of graphs, the weight of a graph might be its number of vertices. If $S$ were the set of finite bit strings (sequences of zeroes and ones), the weight of a bit string might be the number of ones in it. For this problem it doesn’t matter exactly what kind of objects are in $S$ or how these weights are assigned to them. Just imagine that each object in $S$ has a label on which some non-negative integer is written. Then $a_k$ is ...

Comment: ... the number of objects in $S$ whose labels bear the number $k$.